# How to change the time in moment.js to show time like Two and half hours ago

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, momentjs

I am developing an application in which I have used the moment.js to show the pretty time. It is working completely fine other than one of my problem,

If a user updates something 1 hour ago moment.js give "an hour ago" but for the update made hour and half hours ago it again show "an hour ago"

I want it to show the time as "an hour and half ago." and similarly for other hours till 24 hours while the days will be shows as is like "a day ago","2 days ago"

Can I change the moment.js in this way?

Comment: i think you can use countdown timer

Comment: @parsh gami can ui suggest how?

Comment: Like it is display like 1Day 2Hours 10Minutes 30Seconds